# The value of the react state automatically sets to its original value. When a socket event has occurred?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, webrtc

I am building a video calling app by using WebRTC & Socket.io.
I am using Reducer to store the value of Local Stream.
But When the event video:call:accepted occur the value of Local Stream in the State Becomes null

Code Snippet

```
// importing hooks
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";

// importin components
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'
import Navbar from "../Navigation/Navbar";
import { socket } from "../../socket";
import Peer from "./Peer";

const initialState = {
    stream: null
};

const reducer = (previousState, action) => {
    switch (action?.type) {
        case 'stream':
            return { ...previousState, stream: action?.stream };
    }
};

const WebRTC = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

    const turnOnYourVideo = async () => {
        const constraints = {
            audio: true,
            video: true
        }
        const localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
        dispatch({ type: 'stream', stream: localStream });
    }

    const handleCallAccepted = useCallback(({ from, ans }) => {
        // Peer.setLocalDescription(ans);
        console.log('from', from);
        console.log('ans', ans);
        console.log('handleCallAccepted', state?.stream);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        turnOnYourVideo();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('video:call:accepteed', handleCallAccepted);
        return () => {
            socket.off('video:call:accepteed', handleCallAccepted);
        }
    }, []);

    console.log('Local Stream', state?.stream);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Navbar />
            <ReactPlayer url={state?.stream} width='800px' playing muted />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
};
export default WebRTC;
```

[Console Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zog58.png)

During mounting phase the value of stream is null and then it sets to LocalStream but when the event occurred it sets to is original value

Here I want to get the tracks of my LocalStream

Answer (score 0):

Add state?.stream in dependencies array or else

```
useEffect(() => {
       turnOnYourVideo().then(()=>{
socket.on('video:call:accepteed', handleCallAccepted);
       return () => {
           socket.off('video:call:accepteed', handleCallAccepted);
socket.disconnect();
       }
});
   }, []);
```